# Query Error with Having Clause using computed column

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-maps, gps, latitude-longitude

I am trying to find nearest locations based on latitude and longitude by using the locations in  my database.
Here is my query:

```
select *,
acos(cos(33.7103820972222 * (PI()/180)) *
 cos(73.05794 * (PI()/180)) *
 cos(Lat * (PI()/180)) *
 cos(Lon * (PI()/180))
 +
 cos(33.7103820972222 * (PI()/180)) *
 sin(73.05794 * (PI()/180)) *
 cos(Lat * (PI()/180)) *
 sin(Lon * (PI()/180))
 +
 sin(33.7103820972222 * (PI()/180)) *
 sin(73.05794 * (PI()/180))
) * 3959 AS Dist from tblOrg having Dist < 5 order by Dist
```

I am having error in Dist in the below line
`having Dist < 5`.

Comment: `HAVING` should only be used with conditions that include an **aggregate** function like `SUM`, `COUNT` etc. - otherwise, if you **don't have** any aggregate in your condition, use `WHERE` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As marc_s commented "`HAVING` should only be used with conditions that include an aggregate function like `SUM`, `COUNT` etc. - otherwise, if you don't have any aggregate in your condition, use `WHERE` instead"

And you can't access a computed column directly in a `having` or `where` clause. So instead make a sub-query:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    acos(cos(33.7103820972222 * (PI()/180)) *
    cos(73.05794 * (PI()/180)) *
    cos(Lat * (PI()/180)) *
    cos(Lon * (PI()/180))
    +
    cos(33.7103820972222 * (PI()/180)) *
    sin(73.05794 * (PI()/180)) *
    cos(Lat * (PI()/180)) *
    sin(Lon * (PI()/180))
    +
    sin(33.7103820972222 * (PI()/180)) *
    sin(73.05794 * (PI()/180))
    ) * 3959 AS Dist
  from tblOrg
) x
where Dist < 5
order by Dist
```

Comment: I got error **An invalid floating point operation occurred.**

Comment: @SyedSarmadAli - your math is too complex for me to resolve - but I have solved the question you asked. Please ask another one if you are unable to solve the math issue.

Comment: @SyedSarmadAli The normal approach to solving complex computations is to break them down into parts and get each part working then combine them.

Answer (score 0):

This query finally solved my issues.

```
    tblOrg.Id as Id,
    ( 6371  * acos( cos( radians(33.7103820972222) ) 
    * cos( radians( Lat  ) ) 
    * cos( radians( Lon  ) 
    - radians(73.05794) ) 
    + sin( radians(33.7103820972222) ) 
    * sin( radians( Lat ) ) ) ) AS Distance
FROM 
    tblOrg 
) AS P
WHERE
    P.Distance< 5   
ORDER BY
    P.Distance;
```